# How to an Excel file into a link to send in email

Tags: vba, excel

```
Mvalue = MonthName(5, True)
fileL = "\bobby\outside\"

myFile = fileL & Mvalue & Right(Year(Date), 2) & "\Goodbye - " & myfdate & ".xls"

    Set omail = CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With omail

        .Subject = "Hello"
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .HTMLBody = myFile
```

How do I make the `.HTMLBody = myFile`, into a link within the email that will be sent out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an html link:

```
.HTMLBody = "<a href='" & myFile & "'>Linky</a>"
```